blazor wasm: Nuget package inheritance
Is it possible to create a nuget package of a Blazor WASM standalone that has some generic logic inside of it like; authentication, dependency injection etca. That way when I make a package of it and put that package inside of a different Blazor WASM standalone project so I can just use the authentication, dependency injection, same styling etca.
Is this possible, if so is it worth it? Thank you in advance.
So far I've tried looking on stackoverflow and online, also using copilot. I've yet to find anything concrete other than RCLs and creating components.

"Is this possible" - should be, you can have a nupkg that depends on other packages. "is it worth it" - depends, are you doing this once or twice? do customizations may require you to fiddle with the "generic logic?"

Not sure but maybe what you describe could be a project template instead of nuget package: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/ide/how-to-create-project-templates?view=vs-2022 (this would be like creating a new project in VS but instead of using the built in project for blazor wasm standalone you would start with your customized project for blazor wasm standalone).

What I forgot to mention is that I want the index.html to visually be the same, how could I achieve that. Especially regarding that the index.html is like the entry of the entire application
